# How do I use a controller function in another factory in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I wrote a controller and using a function there. I wanna use that function in other factory with controller scope. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not move the function to a service if it is to be used elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't inject controller into factory/Service. Which means you can't use controller functions in factory/Service.

You can inject things into controllers, but you can't inject controllers into things. That's because controllers aren't created via the provider. Instead, there is a built-in Angular service called $controller that is responsible for setting up your controllers.

Reference link:-[Understanding-Dependency-Injection](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection)